# Glide ImageView fit CircleTransformed size

Tags: android, geometry, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm using Glide with CircleTransform to have a circular image into this ImageView.

The ImageView has wrap_content properties however, the ImageView doesn't fit the width of the CircleTransformed Image.

Here is my code : 
My image loading :

```
int itemSizeInDp = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_social);
    int itemSizeInPx = MetricsHelper.convertDpToPx(mContext, itemSizeInDp);
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mSocialPhotos.get(position))
            .transform(new CircleTransform(mContext))
            .override(itemSizeInPx, itemSizeInPx)
            .into(holder.mSocialPhoto);
```

My CircleTransform class :

```
public class CircleTransform extends BitmapTransformation {

public CircleTransform(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.d("photo", "transform");
}
@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap source, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    return ImageUtils.getCircularBitmapImage(source);
}
@Override
public String getId() {
    return "Glide_Circle_Transformation";
}}

public class ImageUtils {
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmapImage(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
    if (squaredBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    squaredBitmap.recycle();
    return bitmap;
}}
```

and the image view :
[image: the image view (the black is the full imageview content)]

is there a way to make my imageview fit the circle width ?

**EDIT:**

I can directly set the ImageView's LayoutParams like below but I think there is definitely a more elegant way to do this.

```
holder.mSocialPhoto.getLayoutParams().height = itemSizeInPx;
holder.mSocialPhoto.getLayoutParams().width = itemSizeInPx;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found a better way to do this,

```
holder.mSocialPhoto.getLayoutParams().height = itemSizeInPx;
holder.mSocialPhoto.getLayoutParams().width = itemSizeInPx;
```

Works just fine.